# how to compile eosio.system contracts?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.system

I cloned the eosio.contracts folder from github and made some changes in some of the contracts. Now I would like to compile them and test them, but when I try to compile them with eosio.cdt I get errors like

```
eosio.cdt/1.6.1/bin/wasm-ld: error: /tmp/eosio.system.cpp.o: undefined symbol: eosiosystem::system_contract::withdraw(...) etc.
```

how do I compile the contracts in eosio.contracts so I can use them when I build/install eos etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you try to build the contracts with the cdt directly?

As the system-contracts are a set of contracts which are typically build with the build-script in addition of a makefile you can't use the cdt to build a single contract without additional changes.

Try to use build.sh located in the root-folder despite the changes you made or you have to add additional modifications to your contracts.